# Volume integral over dyadic: Is it true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3 \vec{x}\; x_i x_j f(|\vec{x}|) \ \propto \ \delta_{ij}$?

Tags: integration, volume, spherical-coordinates, kronecker-delta

Let $f(a)$ be some function of $a>0$. Is it true that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3 \vec{x}\; x_i x_j f(|\vec{x}|) \ \propto \ \delta_{ij}
$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, and where $x_i$ are the cartesian components of $\vec{x}$?

This seems to be true when pick various values for $i$ and $j$. Is there an easy way to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

[Change the variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) by a reflection:
$$I_{12}=\int_{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb R^3}x_1x_2\,f\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}\right)dV$$
$$=\int_{(x_1,-x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb R^3}x_1(-x_2)\,f\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+(-x_2)^2+x_3^2}\right)|{-1}|dV$$
$$=-I_{12}$$
$$\,$$
$$I_{11}=\int_{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb R^3}x_1^2\,f\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}\right)dV$$
$$=\int_{(x_2,x_1,x_3)\in\mathbb R^3}x_2^2\,f\left(\sqrt{x_2^2+x_1^2+x_3^2}\right)|{-1}|dV$$
$$=I_{22}$$